# how to move config xml files from WEB-INF to resources in java spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I study Java spring. I configure spring 4+hibernate4. Now I have done so:

hibernate-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="user" value="pavel"/>
        <property name="password" value="qwerty"/>

        <!-- C3P0 properties  refer: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springapp.mvc.model"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="com.springapp.mvc.dao.impl.HibernateSessionFactoryImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and i have this structure:

[image]

and in web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But i want create file `hibernate-config.xml:`  in `resources` directory. But But I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: see this link: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/.Hopefully u will get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `hibernate-config.xml` file to *resources* directory and in `web.xml` change the param-value from

```
<param-value>/WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml</param-value>
```

to

```
<param-value>classpath:hibernate-config.xml</param-value>
```